# Filter data frame by column name stored in vector

Tags: r, filtering

I try to filter a data frame with a value of `rowSums` and a value contained in some columns. The names of these columns are themselves contained in a vector.

```
          Pred_Top Pred_1 Herb_3 Herb_2 Algae Phytoplkt Herb_1 Pred_2
Pred_Top         0      1      0      0     0         0      0      1
Pred_1           0      0      1      1     0         0      0      0
Herb_3           0      0      0      0     1         0      0      0
Herb_2           0      0      0      0     1         1      0      0
Algae            0      0      0      0     0         0      0      0
Phytoplkt        0      0      0      0     0         0      0      0
Herb_1           0      0      0      0     0         1      0      0
Pred_2           0      0      0      1     0         1      1      0
```

So I am filtering by `rowSums`like this, whithout any issues :

```
mat[rowSums(mat) <= 2, ]
```

And now, I would like to filter by this vector which stores the name of column I want to filter and a value.

```
name <- c("Algae", "Phytoplakt")
mat[, name] == 1
```

At the end, I want a data frame like this

```
          Pred_Top Pred_1 Herb_3 Herb_2 Algae Phytoplkt Herb_1 Pred_2
Herb_3           0      0      0      0     1         0      0      0
Herb_2           0      0      0      0     1         1      0      0
Herb_1           0      0      0      0     0         1      0      0
```

But I can figure out a way to do the 'intersection' of these two filters.

Comment: What about `mat[rowSums(mat) <= 2 & (mat[,"Algae"] == 1 | mat[,"Phytoplakt"] == 1), ]`

Comment: OR `mat[rowSums(mat) <= 2 & rowSums(mat[,name])> 0,]`

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your kind answers. `name` could change in content, so I can't use your solution @Clemsang but @d.b answer was exactly what I was looking for. I feel stupid for not thinking about it.... Please, @d.b create an answer and I will accept it.